# Send mail via port 25

Tags: smtp, port

I need a mailbox who allow SMTP via port 25 without SSL. Reason of this case is simple... I have old device which cannot send email message via other port than 25 and he doesn't like SSL. Do you know mailbox who allow use smtp at port 25? Or maybe do you heave other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any and I don't expect that you find any (at least none that you would want to use). "SMTP for Relay" and "SMTP for Submission" are [different protocols](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#submission-versus-relay) for more than 20 years now. The latter usually requires authentication, which is an extension that is not common for the former.